# AngularJS - Direct links always send user to main page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Any direct links to my angular app end up on the site's front page. What can I do to permit direct linking to specific portions of my site?

For example, in my angular app if someone clicks a nav link to my about page they get there fine. The URL bar reads "http://something.com/about". However, if they enter that url directly they end up on the front page of the site (url is: http://something.com).

No direct links work... they all end up on the front page. In my code I have:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

This is running on nginx, by the way.

But apparently that is not enough to make direct linking work?

Answer (score 1):

yes, as Syntax said, html5 routing requires server-side configuration.

https://coderwall.com/p/mycbiq

[How do I configure IIS for URL Rewriting an AngularJS application in HTML5 mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode)

[AngularJS HTML5 Mode with Yeoman](https://ejd.dev/2013/05/31/angular-html5Mode-with-yeoman/)

Comment: Well, I actually do have the routes defined in my node app (i.e. on the server side). I wonder if I'm getting some sort of fall through?

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the link and navigating is handled by AngularJS, which is working for you. Loading the url and navigating to the correct page is handled by the server. You will need to setup a rewrite rule that will handle this scenario.

**.htaccess (for Apache servers):**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css¦js|html|png) #Add extra extensions needed.
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

**Node.js:**
https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-connect-pushstate

Comment: Something must be off with that... I converted it for use with nginx and the site failed most spectacularly.