# IIS URL Rewrite Rules

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a AngularJS application that utilizes URL Rewriting for linking. My rewrite rule looks like :

```
<rewrite>
<rules> 
  <rule name="MainRule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^api/(.*)" negate="false" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="Default.cshtml" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

I found this solution on SO: [How do I configure IIS for URL Rewriting an AngularJS application in HTML5 mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode) and made one modification to allow my API to pass through.

Essentially, I want to redirect all my requests to `Default.cshtml` EXCEPT calls to my Web API. This works GREAT when I'm I load the app on the base URL like: `localhost/myapp`. However, if I reload the page on a angular route like: `localhost/myapp/dashboard` it fails saying:

```
<Error><Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/myapp/dashboard'.</Message>
<MessageDetail>No type was found that matches the controller named 'dashboard'.</MessageDetail></Error>
```

I have a work around where I did:

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Default" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(?!lib|api|dist|assets|app/|bower|common|main|signalr|templates|bower_components/).*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="Default.cshtml" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

and it worked fine. Any ideas how I can utilize a cleaner solution above and still accomplish the rewrite?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I need to change the pattern and change `{REQUEST_FILE}` to `{REQUEST_URI}` in a couple of places.  See my demo here:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="MainRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="api/(.*)" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="signalr/(.*)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="Default.cshtml" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: that signalr pattern was a lifesaver. Was struggling for a few hours with that. Another point for future users is if you specify your own root path in the startup.cs app.start() you will have issues. I had to remove my root path of "/www" and just leave it all to signalR mapping.

Comment: I love you mate! Your signalr patter was a lifesaver² Just changed it to Admin (my folder application) and worked like a charm. I have no clue what does this mean, cuz I'm just a designer lmao, but it worked. So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If in case you don't have files and you manage it by routes using Angular, my solution was to create the web.config file and add this file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```