# Enabling HTML 5 mode in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing my first SPA in AngularJS but have hit a problem with the routing.

I am trying to enable HTML 5, like this:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        templateUrl: "/angular/components/booking-system/booking-system-template.html"
    });
})
```

but I understand that there is some configuration to be done to the server (IIS). Can anyone point me in the direction of instructions on what needs doing? The various stackoverflow posts on the subject are a little unclear.

Thanks, M

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to configure your server to make the HTML5 mode working. The only thing you need to do is to add

```
<base href="/">
```

to your `<head></head>`.

Be careful as this configuration is applicable only when the app you're running is at the root of the server(for example 'http://myapp.com/').

If you want your app to run in a sub-context e.g. 'http://myapp.com/subapp', you need to specify your base href as following: `<base href="/subapp">`

I hope this solves your problem.

Lukas

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately. I'm getting a 404 on http://localhost:4685/booking-system.

Comment: Added more detail about my route up there ^

Comment: Try to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode

Comment: I did look at that post Lukas but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

If you want html5mode enable,you need make changes on the server side to return your entry point on any URL request. Then angular app will parse URL and load needed page.

Have a loook at this for reference:
**How to: Configure your server to work with html5Mode**
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Answer (score 0):

You should only need one rule in IIS to get this working if you are using `ng-view`.

Firstly you will need the [IIS Url Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

You then need to setup a rule that redirects all routes back to the entry point so that angular picks it up correctly.

Inside the rewrite rule you want something that looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can edit the web.config directly as well using:

```
<rule name="Angular Rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
```

You will also need to make sure the `base` tag is set in the `html`

`<base href="/">`