# Angular JS Route Query String with Special Characters

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I am using Asp.Net with Angular JS in my project. I want to create my route like below.

Required Url Format: http://localhost:9196/hotelname-cityname

eg: http://localhost:9196/magnolia-bengaluru

I want to access these hotel name and city name in my angular app.

I came to know that, I need to rewrite the iis rule and as well as angular app route changes. Please help me how to do this?

Note: I am not using MVC controllers inside my Project.

```
var app = angular.module("rezeapp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
             .when("/:propertyName-:cityName", {
                 templateUrl: "reze_modules/inventory/inventorytemplate.html",
                 controller: "inventorycontroller",
                 resolve: {
                     propertyInventory: function ($route) {
                         console.log($route.current.propertyName);
                         console.log($route.current.cityName);
                     }
                 }
             })
         .when("/property/cart", {
             templateUrl: "reze_modules/inventory/inventorytemplate.html",
             controller: "inventorycontroller",
             resolve: {
                 checkUrl: function ($route) {
                     console.log($route.url());
                 }
             }
         }).otherwise({ redirectTo: "/property/cart" });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
```

**Web.Config Changes:**

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RezEPropertyUrl" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^/*." />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:2}-{R:1}" redirectType="Found"  />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RezEDefaultPage" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^Property/Cart" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/home.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: You are in a right direction. You can access `:propertyName` and `:cityName` values with `$routeParams` in your controller.

Comment: Web.Config changes are pending i think. With the above code, its not hitting the angular route. Please help me on iis rewrite rule also....i have added that code too...

Comment: That's true because the url you provided is not a client side route. You have to put `#` in it: http://localhost:9196/#/hotelname-cityname

Comment: I am using HTML5Mode set to true. # is not required?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26152011/692422