# Azure cloud service web role Angularjs access denied

Tags: azure

We are creating an azure angularjs application. This application is created as a web role in an azure project. After a deploy we get a 403 error:

```
  403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
  You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

All files are copied automatically from the source project via Gulp. They are not included in the project file.

In the project properties we specified in the publish settings that it should "copy all files in this project folder". The main page is an index.html page that should load up the whole angular application. To get the index.html as default page we added this to the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear/>
    <add value="index.html"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Are there other settings we need to adjust?

Answer (score 0):

I may not be able to point out what's wrong with your application but could you please check as following.

1. Just visit your website with `index.html` specified. I mean `http://your-app.cloudapp.net/index.html`. If it works then this could because your `web.config` setting doesn't work.
2. If your got a 404 error, please check the website folder via Remote Desktop. This might because your deployment script (or project setting) was incorrect which caused some files were missing.
3. If it works but got 403 when you clicked some links or buttons to navigated to another angular view, this should because your IIS doesn't support Angular Router. To fix this problem please refer [How do I configure IIS for URL Rewriting an AngularJS application in HTML5 mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode)

Hope this helps

Comment: the problem is that the files are not copied. I suspect this due to not being in the project file, though I checked the All files in this project folder....