# Application angular does not work in subfolder

Tags: angularjs

My application works fine when I was running fine in local iis express. The application was running in the root url like 'http://localhost:61975/login'. 
But in the web server the application was deployed in a folder and now I got the error 404 for all pages, scripts and content, because the app is ignoring the folder.
For instance: 
Should be: http:\www.mydomain\folder\app\controller\mycontroller.js
as is: http:\www.mydomain\app\controller\mycontroller.js ERROR 404.

I already try to put the tag , but does not work too. 
Any help, please?

Tks

Comment: Are you using absolute paths to load your views? You should always use relative paths.

Comment: what server are you using?  maybe can be a problem to the port

Comment: I'm using relative paths, like this one src="Scripts/jquery.min.js". This is a tipicall example of my problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are using html5mode: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` you should be setting the HTML base tag:

```
<base href="/" target="_blank">
```

in your HTML header. This is a common reason why some scripts and assets are ignored.

Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode) question and see if it helps