# AngularJS html5Mode routing problems hosted in IIS 8.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ngroute

I either get a `403.14 - Forbidden` error or a `404 - Not Found` error when I try to navigate through the routes of my AngularJS application.

When I try to navigate to the base URL, I get a 403.

> Example: http://localhost/Board.WebApp/ gives a 403.

For all other routes, I get a 403.

> Example: http://localhost/Board.WebApp/template1 gives a 404.

What seems to be the problem? Here is my code:

**default.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="app">
<head>
    <title>Board</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
    <base href="/Board.WebApp/" />
</head>
<body ng-cloak>
    <section id="local-content" ng-view></section>
</body>
</html>
```

**routes.js**

```
function (module, amd) {
    'use strict';
    var mod = angular.module('routes', ['ngRoute']);
    mod.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: true
        }); // for pushState routing support instead of # hash

        $routeProvider
            .when("/", amd.route(
            {
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller: 'eventController',
                controllerUrl: 'app/controllers/eventController'
            }))
            .when("/template1", amd.route(
            {
                templateUrl: 'views/templates/template1.html',
                controller: 'eventController',
                controllerUrl: 'app/controllers/eventController'
            }))
    }]);
});
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what **amd** is?

Comment: There's a "dot" . in the view path, this is not allowed

Comment: Did you configure your rewrite engine for Html5Mode? If you don't, take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode

Comment: @Fals, the dot is permitted, it's the base path of the app

Comment: @Miguel, no, I didn't configure IIS if that is what you meant... So the answer would be to simply use `html5Mode(false)` to avoid having to use the IIS URL Rewrite module.

Comment: Just comment that lines where you configure html5Mode. it's set to false by default.

Comment: @Fals: AngularAMD is a javascript library written at MIT with it's only goal to integrate AngularJS and RequireJS properly.

Comment: @Win: AMD means Asynchronous Module Definition. It's an API based on CommonJS used for module loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some server-side configuration required if you want to run in HTML5 mode: the server must rewrite links to the application entry point.

Comment: can you elaborate more on that?