# Relative url of resources in ASP.NET Core not working from development to production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, angular, relative-path

I'm struggling with an issue in my ASP.NET Core & Angular 2 application, where it works just great in development, but when publishing to IIS and configuring IIS properly for ASP.NET Core it fails to load the required stylesheets and scripts.

I redirect all requests that don't map to my API routing back to index.html by returning a `VirtualFileResult`. The index.html has a

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data Platform</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Data Platform" />
    <meta charset="utf8" />

    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/vendors.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="platform/content/css/base.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="platform/content/css/bootstrap-overrides.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />

    <script src="lib/vendors.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                "/platform/": { defaultExtension: "js" }
            }
        });

        System.import("/platform/boot");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <data-platform>Initializing...</data-platform>
</body>
</html>
```

The `Startup.cs` configuration is pretty basic:

```
app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

if (string.Equals(env.EnvironmentName, "Development", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseFileServer(false);
app.UseStatusCodePages();
app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
{
    routeBuilder.MapRoute(
        name: "Api",
        template: "api/{controller}/"
    );
    routeBuilder.MapRoute(
        name: "Client Passthrough",
        template: "{*any}",
        defaults: new { Controller = "ClientPassthrough", Action = "Index" }
    );
});
```

The ClientPassthrough controller action is very basic:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return new VirtualFileResult("~/index.html", "text/html");
}
```

Works fine in development, fails miserably in production. I've tried changing the base href to be `~/` which will point the subsequent urls to the proper application root instead of the server root... but it still can't seem to find those css files or scripts in the `/wwwroot/` folder.

Comment: when you say cant find those css files: if index.html is requested correctly you should see all css file request in for example chrome developer network and have more clues there

Comment: Do F12 in chrome and check the Network tab, that will tell you where it is trying to load the files from and give you clues about your problem.

Comment: I did use chrome tools guys. It looks like it's referencing the files from where it should, domain/app/lib/css/styles.css or whatever. The tilde relative url is also doing some wonky things with the urls... domain/app/~/lib/css/styles.css

Really I can't figure it out. I've given up for now and will worry about it closer to production and closer to RTM of asp.net

Comment: When you deploy to IIS are you using sub applications or just the root site? https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/14

Comment: do you really need the client passthrough? is not working for you to have configured: app.UseDefaultFiles(); app.UseStaticFiles();

Comment: @vinjenzo The only reason I have that is I can't seem to get the full path back to the client for angular 2 routing to process. DefaultFiles() only gives them the app root in the url. If you know of a better way, please let me know!

Tratcher I will check that out. I think I saw that page before but got bogged down in the early postings instead of the later ones. Will check it out and update if that works.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .NET Core with Razor you can add the following code to set your base URL to the URL of the IIS app you are publishing to.

```
<base href="@(Url.Content("~"))" />
```

This code should go in the `<head>` just below the `<title>` element.

Then when you reference the root use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/vendors.css" />
```

Without the slash in front of the path. This is what worked for me.

If you try to use `<base href="/" />` or `<base href="~/" />`, IIS won't know what to do with it because the tilde has no meaning unless it gets parsed by .NET as opposed to served up as text in a page.

Hope that this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to use the url rewrite, maybe in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode) you get more hints too, in case you want to try:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!--Redirect selected traffic to index -->
    <rule name="Index Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/api/" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Togheter with, in the `Startup.cs` file:

```
 app.UseDefaultFiles();

 app.UseStaticFiles();
```

No more client through in mvc config, I guess...

I am missing why the full path should be returned, if it is already available at client endpoint calls.