# Routing 404 error when published Angular 7 app

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have an angular 7 application. My application working my local without any problem. But when I published, I get 404 error. I'm using `PathLocationService`. `Providers` part of `app.module.ts` is like below. I tried also publishing by `ng build --prod --aot --source-map=false --base-href`. But, also not worked. What can be the reason of this? (**When I go www.mywebsite.com/index.html I can see my loading bar. But www.mywebsite.com/MyPage then I get 404 error.**)

```
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true },
    UserService, DatePipe, AuthGuard, RoleGuard, FormBuilder
  ],
```

Comment: Which webserver are you using to serve your application? apache for example needs a htaccess file to support the routing.

Comment: I'm using IIS (Windows server 2012 R2). @maio290

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600609/4934937

Comment: I used --base-href as follows - `ng build --prod --aot --source-map=false --base-href ./` & got it working on IIS

Comment: Your must always fallback to index.html to work. See this [official link](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)

Comment: I tried add web.config from your link. My 404 error gone. But now, I'm taking  `Unexpected token <` error @maio290

Comment: Unexpected token is a javascript error, this does have nothing in common with the routing.

Comment: But, I think it dependent to publishing. Because, in my local I didn't take any error or warning. @maio290

Comment: Yeah, but that's not related to the question here and you should try to find the error on your own. You got the console, you got the source code :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot @maio290 . If you write as an answer your first comment. Then I can mark as an answer.

Comment: That not worked @TusharWalzade

Comment: try that without using .htaccess or web.config

Comment: Actually, @KiraAG had the better answer imho - the reason why is better explained on the Angular page itself, so I guess he'd deserve the Karma more ;)

Comment: You're very fair man :) Thanks @maio290

Comment: I removed web.config but also not worked @TusharWalzade