# Deploying angularjs application to IIS , browser asks for password

Tags: angularjs, html, iis, deployment, url-rewriting

I am about to deploy my application on IIS, I have set `html5mode` to true and have put the following rewrite rule in my `web.config` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode/26152011#26152011) SO answer, but I have a very strange problem, when I refresh on one of my routers, a browser popup appears and asks for username and password. does any one know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Disable HTTP-Auth? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c270506-79bd-41e9-8d96-8a9fc81d9e09

Comment: @lin Only anonymous authentication is enabled and everything else is disabled.