# Angular UI Router works only on more than three directory in url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Why my Angular Router works only when directory is more than 3 (three). if not I'm getting error 404 when I refresh the browser

```html
state('new', {
  url: '/new', // works when I use /new/x/x/x
  templateUrl: 'new.html'
})
```

I am using asp.net mvc

Comment: if you are getting a 404 when you refresh the browser, then your server is handling the routes, not angular, and it is not configured properly.  More than likely (but not shown here), you are *probably* using HTML5Mode, which requires your server to be configured specially.

Comment: you should be using parent-child-child-... nested states to achieve your result

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 404, it means you are usign `HTML5Mode` (cleaning hashbangs from url). So you must have a `.htaccess` file in your project. Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On  
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /yourProjectName/index.html
```

**Note:** change `yourProjectName` to your directory name.

**Edit:** For `IIS` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26152011/4055329) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059745/4055329).

Comment: So you must search for the related one for IIS.

Comment: but why when I refresh in url /new/x/x/x I didn't get any error

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any directory like `/new/x/x/x` in your project?

Comment: yes I don't have. I think its because of route config basic /controller/function/id so I'm am still finding related IIS for your answer in my app

Answer (score -3):

trying to use something like this

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/users',{
            templateUrl: '/views/users.html',
            controller: 'usersController'
        })
        .when('/roles',{
            templateUrl: '/views/roles.html',
            controller: 'rolesController'
        })
        .otherwise(
            { redirectTo: '/'}
        );
```

Comment: how is this related to UI-Router ***states***?

Comment: He is using UI Router not, ngRoute.

Comment: where is the answer for the question.