# Angular2/4 in .net MVC app browser refresh failure

Tags: c#, angular

I am developing a web application using Angular 2/4 but cannot get the browser to refresh the current page.  Running IIS 8.5,  and I have implemented the Angular.io solution of a URL rewrite in the web.config (https://angular.io/guide/deployment) and the S.O. ([How do I configure IIS for URL Rewriting an AngularJS application in HTML5 mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode/26152011#26152011)) but both fail to put the user back on the same page they were. Additionally, when I refresh the user is redirected back to "home" but the enterprise authentication token fails.

Answer (score 0):

The `<base href="/.../">` value in `index.html` must correspond to your URL rewrite.