# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in inline.bundle.js:1 - Angular v4

Tags: javascript, angular, iis, deployment, unexpected-token

After deployment to IIS I found out that none of my routes work, Hence I researched then found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26152011/2116927) in which says that you have to add a rewrite to `web.config`, which I did and routes are working now.

Here is some of my routes that work in development mode, but in production :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'manage', component: ManageComponent },
  { path: 'manage/products', component: ProductComponent },
  { path: 'manage/products/:action/:id', component: ProductComponent },
  { path: 'manage/companies', component: CompanyComponent },
];
```

And what I did in `web.config` :

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*"/>
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/"/>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

So what the actual problem is? The problem raises when I refresh/redirect the page. After an hour research found out that the rule I wrote in `web.config` always returns `index.html` and that's why I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in the following files :

```
inline.bundle.js:1
polyfills.bundle.js:1
styles.bundle.js:1
vendor.bundle.js:1
main.bundle.js:1
```

What do you suggest to fix this?

**Update:** By removing `manage` from routes fixed the problem for routes without parameter, but the problem is still there for routes containing parameter.

Comment: `After an hour research found out that the rule I wrote in web.config always returns index.html` - well, don't do that

Comment: @JaromandaX so what should I do to make my routes work if I don't do that?

Comment: can't see what you did, you probably did it wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX I've added my routes, please take a look.

Comment: Have you seen this configuration for IIS(conditions)? https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers

Comment: @yurzui Yes, you can see it in my last update (codes of web.config)

Answer (score 5):

Had this same problem.  Fixed by changing my base href tag in index.html to the fully qualified base url.

**Before:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MySubApp</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">


  </head>

  <body>
    <mu-root></mu-root>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

**After:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MySubApp</title>
    <base href="http://MyUrl.com/MySubApp/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">


  </head>

  <body>
    <mu-root></mu-root>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

Not 100% clear why exactly, but it appears the way IIS rewrites urls changes how the base root gets passed which was breaking the relative path "/" base-href.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it... but I only put the directory of my app on the IIS server.  I now call ng build --configuration=prodcution --base-href='/app_folder/' when building my Angular 6 application.

Comment: I have a feeling that the above code would work if you just used `<base href="/MySubApp/">`