# Windows IIS - 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: iis, routes, polymer, http-status-code-404, polymer-2.x

When running a `polymer-shop-app` on `localhost` I can go to `localhost:8080/page` and it loads, as well as on a page refresh.

However, once deployed in IIS, I can navigate to `localhost:8080/page` through the app, but one a page refresh I get a `404 - File or directory not found` error.

Is there something that can be set within IIS to change this behavior and properly load the route and route data on a page refresh.

Comment: You'll need to configure IIS to redirect to your root, where your app router can process the route. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26152011/6277151

Comment: That worked. Thanks Tony!!