# AngularUI routing always shows me /#/home in the url header

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have an angularJS app with Angular-UI framework routing. I have a bit problem which when I go to forum.html page via ui-sref link I get

> mywebsite/#/home

at the header so I expect the url to be

> mywebsite/#/Forum

another question how to get rid off hash sign (#) in url header

```
  app.config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state("home",{
            url:"home",
            views:{
                'main':{templateUrl:"index.html"}
            }
        })
     .state("forum",{
            url:"forum",
            views:{
                'main3':{templateUrl:"forum.html"}
            }
        });
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
         $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
         }); 

       <div class="container" style="margin-top: 60px">
       <div ui-view="main"></div>
       <div ui-view="main3"></div>
       </div>
```

Forum.html

```
<div>
<div class="tab-content">
<div ui-view="main3"></div>
 forum 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For url, please change:

```
url:"home"
url:"forum"
```

To:

```
url:"/home"
url:"/forum"
```

To remove # sign, please use the following code:

```
app.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

And add the following:

```
<head>
    ...
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

According to your comments, a minimum version of code is attached here:

> app.js

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  var homeState = {
    name: 'home',
    views: {
        'main': {
          template: "<p> home</p>"
        }
      }
  }

  var storeState = {
    name: 'store',
    views: {
        'main': {
          template: "<p> Store</p>"
        }
      }
  }

  $stateProvider.state(homeState);
  $stateProvider.state(storeState);

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

});
```

> index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
         <script src="app.js"></script>
         <style>.active { color: red; font-weight: bold; }</style>
         <base href="/">
    </head>
<body data-spy="scroll"  data-offset="53"    ng-app="app" style="background-image:url('silver.jpg')">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:#84b1f9;">
    <div class="navbar-header" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px white">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#c1">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="c1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-active="active" style="background-color:#84b1f9; color:black;" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="store" ui-sref-active="active" style="color:black;">Store</a></li>

        </ul>
        <p class="navbar-text" style="color: #ec971f"> </p>

    </div>
</nav>


    <div ui-view="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed my code  to  app.config(function 
 ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider)  { $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); ); but links doesn't work

Comment: Have you changed url:"home", url:"forum" to url:"/home"
url:"/forum", a forward slash / is added.

Comment: Strange! with this code destroy the whole design and route of my app I see only one page with navbar  index page color  <base href="/">

Comment: Depending on your webserver you also need to do some configuration for html5 mode, for example with IIS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode

Comment: @bramve xampp Apache server

Comment: <a href="/home" ui-sref-active="active" style="background-color:#84b1f9; color:black;">Home</a> , change: ui-sref to href, fiddle is not complete. After changing I am getting not found error as the file not exists.

Comment: Also, angular library is missing:<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: If I do that the url would be localhost/home or localhost/store and the page is not found error is been get complete code here https://fiddle.jshell.net/vg0bhr2c/10/

Comment: yes. That means your router is now working. Properly, set the path for templateUrl:"index.html", templateUrl:"forum.html"

Comment: views:{
                'main3':{templateUrl:"forum.html"}
         }, is also wrong, it will be views:{
                'main':{templateUrl:"forum.html"}
         }

Comment: You can check using template rather than templateUrl ------template:"<p> Template home </p>", template:"<p> Template forum </p>"

Comment: Have you used hard coded template value as I given top.

Comment: yes I Have used hard coded template value as  you given top.