# Angular 4 - Getting IIS error 404 page instead redirect to my 404 page accordind to user permissions

Tags: angular, iis, routes, angular4-router

I'm building an Angular 4 web application that have some restricted pages according to user permissions. I'm blocking the user access using the `canActivate` router property. If the user don't have the permission to access that page, it is redirect to a 404 error page that I developed.

Route example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '', component: PageComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'indicadores', loadChildren: './indicadores/indicadores.module#IndicadoresModule', canActivate: [PermissoesService] }]}];
```

CanActivate Method:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    let path = state.url.split('\/')[1];
    if (!this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        if(this.getRoutePermission(path)) return true;
        else {
            this.route.navigate(['/404']);
        }
    }
}
```

The application is stored on a IIS server. When I'm developing and testing on local machine using `ng serve`, the app works fine. But when I deploy the app to the server, I try to access a router that the user don't have permission, the application redirects to IIS 404 page instead my 404 page.

Is there an additional configuration on the server or in the code?

Comment: Yep, you need to ensure IIS falls back to `index.html` https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: It works! I followed these steps that de angular docs suggest and I got error 500, but I realized that was missing the <configure> tag in the web.config.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode/26152011#26152011