# Deploy Angular on Azure with static website fallback problem

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy my Angular app to the Azure static websites. I configured the environment following this tutorial: [Medium tutorial for Azure static websites](https://medium.com/@squalrus/cutting-hosting-costs-by-99-with-static-websites-on-azure-44483b6b2c3f)

The problem that I have is the fallback in the case I try to access for example myurl.com/mypage (with only myurl.com is working correctly).

I'm building Angular with `ng build --prod`.

As it's running on IIS, I've tried the following web.config: [web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26152011/7604006), I put it in /src folder and I've changed angular.json as follows:

```
"assets": [
     ...
     "src/web.config"
],
```

and it's placing the file in the root folder which is correct.

My problem is that I'm still getting 404 when I try to access `myurl.com/mypage`

Comment: Jorciney's answer is amazing.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify your [fallback route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/routes#fallback-routes) by creating a file called routes.json in src/assets. It should contain:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "serve": "/index.html",
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the below provider in your app.module.ts should be enough:

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

Example:

```
...other imports
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help somebody else:

On your Storage Account -> Static website
you will find:
[image]

**Both should be index.html**

Answer (score 1):

I specified staticwebapp.config.json file with the following contents in the src folder. This worked for me and resolved the deep linking issue on the Angular site. I also had "useHash" enabled. Hope this helps someone. I initially tried this fix on the new Azure Static Web App but this rewrite is also working on Azure Storage-Static Web site.

```
 {
   "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html",
     "exclude": [ "/images/*.{png,jpg,gif,ico}", "/*.{css,scss,js}" ]
   }
 }
```

Comment: i dont want to use hash in routing.